# What are the different [para-]rabbinic roles in the UK?

Tags: rabbis, chutz-laaretz, organizations

If you look at the ["Our Rabbis" page](http://www.theus.org.uk/local_communities/our_rabbis/) on the website of the United Kingdom's [United Synagogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Synagogue), you'll find people with the personal titles "Rabbi" or "Reverend," and with the organizational roles "Rabbi" or "Minister." (I'm leaving out Dayanim on the [London Beth Din](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Beth_Din).)

What are the differences between a rabbi and a reverend, and what are the differences between a congregation's Rabbi and its Minister? Am I dividing these concepts up correctly?

Comment: It was used as a title in America also (There was a Rev. Shifrin who was the head of [Agudas Chassidei Chabad in America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agudas_Chasidei_Chabad) until he passed away in the 1940s.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, in the US, it was more of a practicality than a formal title. My grandfather ז”ל, a chazzan, used it for legal purposes, as it afforded certain privileges such as lower property taxes and phonebook perks.

Answer (score 2):

Reverand is a title for people who act as Rabbis but lack Smicha.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reverend#Judaism)

(I know it's not a good source, but I heard the same from other places.)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding was that a Reverend is a person who works as a "Pulpit Rabbi", being in charge of a congregation and caring for their life cycle events.  However, such a person is not qualified for complicated halachic rulings, and should not be consulted on non-lifecycle or Shul related questions.

I have no source other than my own limited exposure to the terms.

Comment: This is my understanding from folks I know who grew up in fromm communities in the UK.