# "Reverend" as title for a Rabbi?

Tags: commentaries, rashi, pentateuch-chumash, reform-judaism

I came across a Chumash Rashi with the supercommentary of Dr. Silbermann and "Rev." Rosenbaum.

Does this abbreviation mean "Reverend"? Am I correct to assume that Dr. Rosenbaum was therefore a very liberal, reformed Rabbi? Can this supercommentary be classified as orthodox?

Thank you,
Thomas

Comment: Thank you. What "denomination" were Silberman and Rosenberg?

Comment: Rev. Rosenberg was an Orthodox rabbi in England. You can scroll down and read about him here: https://www.jewishgen.org/jcr-uk/Profiles/minister_profiles_orthodox_R.htm I assume his co-author, the Hungarian born lexicographer Dr. Silbermann was Orthodox as well.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the volume you're looking at is [*Pentateuch with Rashi's Commentary Translated into English*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_Commentary_Translated_into_English), by Rev. Morris Rosenbaum and Dr. Abraham Silbermann. According to the Wikipedia article linked above, the former was an early-Twentieth-Century UK Rabbi. As noted in [this previous Q&A](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14721/what-are-the-different-para-rabbinic-roles-in-the-uk), "Reverend" is a title used in the UK to designate a congregational spiritual leader who doesn't have rabbinic ordination, including in the Orthodox-aligned and predominant [United Synagogue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Synagogue).

Comment: A corollary note from a friend who received semichah from Jews College: The Rt. Rev. R' Dr. Hermann Adler ז"ל desired to be the only רב in the United Synagogue and, consequently, made certain that no one was given the title of "Rabbi," a practice which remained until the tenure of the Lord Jakobovitz ז"ל as Chief Rabbi. (Similarly, all dayanim in the US were trained abroad, primarily in Lita, until the establishment of the Gateshead Yeshiva provided a venue for semichah on UK soil)